# matching and verifying Express 3/Connect 2 session keys from socket.io connection

Tags: express, socket.io

I have a good start on a technique similar to this in Express 3
http://notjustburritos.tumblr.com/post/22682186189/socket-io-and-express-3

the idea being to let me grab the session object from within a socket.io connection callback, storing sessions via `connect-redis` in this case.

So, in `app.configure` we have

```
var db = require('connect-redis')(express)
....
app.configure(function(){
     ....
     app.use(express.cookieParser(SITE_SECRET));                                                                                                      
     app.use(express.session({ store: new db }));
```

And in the app code there is

```
var redis_client = require('redis').createClient()

 io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {
     if (!data.headers.cookie) {
         return accept('Sesssion cookie required.', false)
     }

     data.cookie = require('cookie').parse(data.headers.cookie);
     /* verify the signature of the session cookie. */
     //data.cookie = require('cookie').parse(data.cookie, SITE_SECRET);
     data.sessionID = data.cookie['connect.sid']

     redis_client.get(data.sessionID, function(err, session) {
         if (err) {
             return accept('Error in session store.', false)
         } else if (!session) {
             return accept('Session not found.', false)
         }
         // success! we're authenticated with a known session.
         data.session = session
         return accept(null, true)
     })
 })
```

The sessions are being saved to redis, the keys look like this:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "sess:lpeNPnHmQ2f442rE87Y6X28C"
2) "sess:qsWvzubzparNHNoPyNN/CdVw"
```

and the values are unencrypted JSON. So far so good.

The cookie header, however, contains something like

```
{ 'connect.sid': 's:lpeNPnHmQ2f442rE87Y6X28C.obCv2x2NT05ieqkmzHnE0VZKDNnqGkcxeQAEVoeoeiU' }
```

So now the SessionStore and the `connect.sid` don't match, because the signature part (after the `.`) is stripped from the SessionStore version.

Question is, is is safe to just truncate out the SID part of the cookie (lpeNPnHmQ2f442rE87Y6X28C) and match based on that, or should the signature part be verified? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather than hacking around with private methods and internals of Connect, that were NOT meant to be used this way, this NPM does a good job of wrapping `socket.on` in a method that pulls in the session, and parses and verifies
https://github.com/functioncallback/session.socket.io

Comment: This also looks nice. Seems to be elegant.. I wonder if it has any drawbacks vs. just passing the store variable to the socket.io and performing lookups when you want?

Answer (score 2):

Just use cookie-signature module, as recommended by the comment lines in Connect's utils.js.

var cookie = require('cookie-signature');

//assuming you already put the session id from the client in a var called "sid"

```
var sid = cookies['connect.sid'];
sid = cookie.unsign(sid.slice(2),yourSecret);
if (sid == "false") {
   //cookie validation failure
   //uh oh. Handle this error
} else {
   sid = "sess:" + sid;
    //proceed to retrieve from store
}
```